# Insert contact programmatically in android 4.0 is not showing in default contact list

Tags: android

I'm doing an Android application which insert contacts programmatically.I've added one contact using below code. Its adding up well but I couldn't see that contact on default device contact list. My device version is 4.0.4. But its showing well & good on other devices.Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
private void createContact(String name, String phone) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                    "accountname@gmail.com")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                    "com.google").build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    name).build());// Display name comes here
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone)// Phone number comes up here
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
            .build());

    try {
        cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ACCOUNT_TYPE should be "com.google"

Comment: @pskink Both ACCOUNT_NAME & ACCOUNT_TYPE should be "com.google"?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html